# Quadratic regression with weight in r

Tags: r

An analytical instrument is calibrated.  The calibration curve is built with a quadratic regression with a weight (1/x).

What algorithm in R could I use to simulate this practice?

Comment: Check the `weight` argument of the `lm()`-function! Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Serkan, yes, it is.  I use:

lm(y, ~ poly(x,2)), weights = 1/x).  

Thank you

Comment: I guess, Ill add an answer for future reference then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check the `weight` argument of the `lm()`-function;

```r
# Weighted;
lm(
        formula = mpg ~ poly(hp,2),
        weights = (1/hp),
        data = mtcars
)

# Unweighted;
lm(
        formula = mpg ~ poly(hp,2),
        data = mtcars
)
```

As briefly discussed in the comments.